# вывести столбец в виде ссылки

Tags: php

Добрый вечер уважаемые знатоки. Есть маленькая проблема (так как, я ноль в PHP  вынужден обратится к вам).

Есть таблица vopros  из нее надо вывести столбец vopros, и каждую строку представить в виде ссылки:

```
 $out ="SELECT DISTINCT vopros FROM vopros";
 $rez=$pdo->prepare($out);
 $rez->execute();
 $tabl=$rez->fetchAll();
 foreach ($tabl as $key => $value) {
    echo "".'<a href="">'.$tabl."</a><br/>";
 }
```

Comment: В чём проблема/ошибка. Расскажите поподробнее как формируется URL, откуда берётся id вопроса?

Comment: `echo "".'<a href="PATH/TO' . $value.vopros  . '">'. $value.vopros."</a><br/>";`

Comment: id вопроса тоже должно выводится из таблицы ( только я никак не пойму как написать... просто выходит  в виде ссылки array, а не содержимое(((

Comment: а мне нужно чтобы содержимое по строкам выходило в виде ссылки,чтобы при нажатии на вопрос отправляла на форму ответа

Comment: так а почему вы начинаете перебирать $tabl, но внутри цикла перебора выводите его же?

Comment: это я исправил, там $value  должно быть , но все равно ...

Comment: Поправьте код в финальный вариант,  покажите структуру таблицы и что получается на выходе - и что в нем не так :)

Comment: сделайте print_r() массива и покажите что там у вас

Comment: https://vk.com/photo335221430_456239105 вот таблица, надо вывести столбец vopros так чтобы каждая запись выходила в виде ссылки

Comment: $out ="SELECT DISTINCT vopros FROM vopros";
  $rez=$pdo->prepare($out);
  $rez->execute();
  $tabl=$rez->fetchAll();
  foreach ($tabl as $key => $value) {     
  echo "".'<a href="">'.$value."</a><br/>";
  }

Comment: 1. Дополняйте ваш вопрос, а не в комментариях пишите. Испраляйте там ошибки. Дополняйте. 2) А ссылка куда должна вести? Какого она вида? Что за дичь вы вообще хотите?

Comment: я извиняюсь за неудобства ((((.... спасибо всем ))))

Comment: так что в итоге?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
 $out ="SELECT DISTINCT vopros FROM vopros";
 $rez=$pdo->prepare($out);
 $rez->execute();
 $tabl=$rez->fetchAll();
 foreach ($tabl as $value) {
    echo "".'<a href="">'.$value."</a><br/>";
 }
```

Информация про [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Gleb, спасибо большое))) кому нибудь пригодиться )) а я сам допер)))